# sf-menu dropdown menu not showing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get dropdown menu on my blog, but it has fruitless. I believe dropdown menu exist in the theme because I can see some proof in the CSS. This is my first time here, so I will try to be very specific

```
 <div id='nav1-wrapper'>
<div id='nav1'>
        <ul class='sf-menu sf-js-enabled'>


<li class='cat-item'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' title='Home'>Home</a></li>
          <ul>
        <li>
        <a href=''><span>About Us</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <li class='cat-item'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default&quot;' title='Posts RSS'>Posts RSS</a></li>
    <li class='cat-item'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/comments/default&quot;' title='Comments RSS'>Comments RSS</a></li>
    <li class='cat-item'><a href='#' title='Edit this link'>Edit</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In a Test mode, I was trying to get the "About" under Home, but it doesn't work, rather it becomes a new main menu.

here is the CSS

```
    #nav1-wrapper {

}
#nav1 {
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 37px;
        width:978px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
    background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_WoCJXgXotb8/SukuVz4pzoI/AAAAAAAABVM/IjgR927kxe8/s1600/nav1-sep.png) no-repeat left top;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li {
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_WoCJXgXotb8/SukuVz4pzoI/AAAAAAAABVM/IjgR927kxe8/s1600/nav1-sep.png) no-repeat right top;
    float: left;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 1px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li a {
    color: #666666;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
        font-weight:bold;
    padding:0 13px 0 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
        letter-spacing:-0.01em;
        font-size:14px;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #333333;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li a:active{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 36px;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #272726 url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_WoCJXgXotb8/Suk0OoE_6LI/AAAAAAAABV8/40qI1cTpwfU/s1600/ul_children_bg.gif) repeat-y top right;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children li {
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_WoCJXgXotb8/Suk0vKvLK4I/AAAAAAAABWE/18lJ8uP1Aes/s1600/ul_children_li_bg.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children li a {
    color: #bebebe;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children li ul.children {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: none;
    background: #272726 url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_WoCJXgXotb8/Suk3Qj6Zi4I/AAAAAAAABWM/vwv6kTkSeG4/s1600/ul_children_ul_children_bg.gif) repeat-y top left;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children li ul.children li {
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_WoCJXgXotb8/Suk0vKvLK4I/AAAAAAAABWE/18lJ8uP1Aes/s1600/ul_children_li_bg.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children li ul.children a {
    color: #bebebe;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children
{
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
}
#nav1 ul.sf-menu li ul.children ul.children
{
    margin:-1px 0 0 27px;
}
```

I edited the question so as to bring the full html and css code. Thanks
url: http://thebusywire.blogspot.com/

Comment: Just to note, you have a ul as a direct child of another ul. That should not be there.

Comment: A part from the closing tags missing (one `</ul>` and one `</div>`), copy-pasting your code in Jsfiddle gives me the exact behaviour you are searching: About as a child of Home: http://jsfiddle.net/jButp/

Comment: So do I remove the first ul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the class "children" to the ul containing the child. In this case "About Us".

```
<ul class='sf-menu sf-js-enabled'>
    <li class='cat-item'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' title='Home'>Home</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>
                <a href=''><span>About Us</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='cat-item'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default&quot;' title='Posts RSS'>Posts RSS</a></li>
    <li class='cat-item'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/comments/default&quot;' title='Comments RSS'>Comments RSS</a></li>
    <li class='cat-item'><a href='#' title='Edit this link'>Edit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi veelen, Thanks for your response, I have tried doing that and nothing happens.

Comment: You are right. That's because the children ul is not in a li of the menu ul. You have to put ul.children in a li.cat-item of the ul.sf-menu

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark my answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: Hi, I inserted the code, it seems we are almost there. but something is still wrong. I left the code on my blog so you can take a look. Thanks so much  http://thebusywire.blogspot.com/

Comment: My mistake. The ul.children has to be part of the li of the parent. I edited the code again.

Comment: I'm sorry for talking much of your time, Now we have a static dropdown menu but shifts the main-wrapper to right.  Please take a look at the blog again. Thanks.

Comment: The head of your page is a bit of a mess, so i can't really figure out if you have included the needed jquery script for this menu. If you didn't, thats the reason why it shows up like it does.

Comment: It's the default template. I am sure the author made some few errors. Thanks very much for your help. I will mark it as answered, maybe it can work for others. I really do appreciate.